# Splitting laravel query returns massive odd result

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this query in Laravel (5.3):

```
$menu_categories = DB::table('categories')->get();
```

It returns the categories from the database as expected. However, if I split it (so that I can add other parameters):

```
$menu_categories = DB::table('categories');
$menu_categories->get();
```

It returns a massive collection that starts like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder Object
(
    [connection:protected] => Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection Object
        (
            [pdo:protected] => PDO Object
                (
                )

            [readPdo:protected] => 
            [reconnector:protected] => Closure Object
                (
                    [this] => Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager Object...
```

What is happening here? I've searched for a while and can't find anything on this - although I admit I'm not sure what to search for. Note that I am NOT adding any additional parameters when it has the weird return collection - I saw the weird return initially with extra params (orderBy and whereIn) but even after removing those it still returns this weirdness.

Comment: You have to save the query result in a variable: `$menu_categories = $menu_categories->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The "non split" line is creating a query object for the categories table, calling get() on the query object and assigning the results of get() to the $menu_categories variable.
2. In the split version, the first line creates a query object for the categories table and sets it in the $menu_categories variable.

   In the second line, calling get() on $menu_categories doesn't actually mutate the variable.  Instead it returns the collection that you're looking for but it's not being assigned to anything.  This is why you just see this massive object when you dump it.

The correct 2 line version would look something like this:

```
$query_object = DB:table('categories');
$menu_categories = $query_object->get();
```

Comment: Ah - got it. Thanks.